# Accessing REST-API / XML-Result with Javascript, jquery-find, find Attributes with same name but different Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I have build a HTML-Page which should display a table of alarms.
We get the alarms via a REST-API from another tool on the same server.

The problem is:
The alarm consists of different attributes which are marked  with different IDs in the XML-Result.
How could I access the different attributes by jquery.find().
Actually I use jquery - eq()  but I would like to access them by the right "id" and not by an "index" which could change to fast.
Any other good hint how to acces the right attributes via Javascript?

The REST-Response (XML) result. ... shortened.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<alarm-response-list xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response" error="EndOfResults" throttle="2" total-alarms="2">
    <alarm-responses>
    <alarm id="51b87e2f-0006-1000-012f-00801000af00">
        <attribute id="0x129fa">0x70033e</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x1000a">4</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x12b4c">DEVICE IN MAINTENANCE MODE</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11fc4">0</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11f50">66082</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11f4e">1371045423</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x1006e">192.168.200.3</attribute>
    </alarm>
    <alarm id="52c0a012-a488-1009-02bf-00801000af00">
        <attribute id="0x129fa">0x70033f</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x1000a">3</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x12b4c">DEVICE HAS STOPPED RESPONDING TO POLLS</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11fc4">0</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11f50">65545</attribute>
        <attribute id="0x11f4e">1388355602</attribute>
                <attribute id="0x1006e">192.168.2.1</attribute>
    </alarm>
    </alarm-responses>
</alarm-response-list>
```

My Script....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Alarmlist</title>
<meta xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head><body>
<table id="alarmlist" name="alarmlist"><tr><td>AlarmID</td><td>attr0x129fa</td><td>attr0x1000</td><td>attr0x1000a</td></tr></table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost/spectrum/restful/alarms?attr=0x129fa&attr=0x1000a&attr=0x0012b4c&attr=0x00011fc4&attr=0x11f50&attr=0x11f4e&attr=0x1006e',
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) { 
                    $(xml).find('alarm').each(function () { 

                    var attr0x129fa = $(this).find('attribute').eq(0).text(); // without eq(), the response includes all attribute-values!
                    var attr0x1000a = $(this).find('attribute').eq(1).text();
                    var attr0x12b4c = $(this).find('attribute').eq(2).text();

                    $('<tr><td> - - ' + attr0x129fa + '</td><td>' + attr0x1000a + '</td><td>' + attr0x12b4c + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#alarmlist');                       
                        });
                        },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
        });
    });
  </script>


END
</body>
</html>
```

First I used only

```
var alarm = $(this).find('attribute').text();
```

The result was a long text with all attribute-values.. concatinated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to get attribute nodes by id:

```
var alarm = $(this).find("attribute[id='0x129fa']").text();
```

... should return `0x70033e`